# How to handle nested context?

Tags: javascript, python, mustache

I wanted to use nested dictionaries in [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com), section **Non-False Values** in [Mustache manual](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html) suggests it's possible and presents the following example:

**Template:**

```js
{{#person?}}
  Hi {{name}}!
{{/person?}}
```

**Hash:**

```js
{
   "person?": { "name": "Jon" }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hi Jon!
```

I tried to run above example in [online demo](http://mustache.github.com/#demo) and I got:

```
Hi !
```

I also tried [pystache](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache) (pystache 0.3.1, Python 2.7.2):

```python
import pystache

tmpl = """
{{#person}}
  Hi {{name}}!
{{/person}}
"""

dct = {
  "person": { "name": "Jon" }
}

print(pystache.render(tmpl, dct))
```

And I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(pystache.render(tmpl, dct))
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pystache\__init__.py", line 7, in render
    return Template(template, context).render()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pystache\template.py", line 42, in render
    template = self.render_sections(template, context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pystache\template.py", line 78, in render_sections
    insides.append(self.render(inner, item))
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pystache\template.py", line 43, in render
    result = self.render_tags(template, context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pystache\template.py", line 97, in render_tags
    replacement = func(self, tag_name, context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pystache\template.py", line 105, in render_tag
    raw = context.get(tag_name, '')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I had no problems with lists, so structure like below worked fine:

```js
{
   "person?": [{ "name": "Jon" }]
}
```

I can make a work-around by input dict preprocessing (flattening or changing dictionaries to lists), but why it doesn't work? Am I doing something wrong?

---

### Solution of pystache problem

Version of pystache located in [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org) is really old (from May 2010) and that's the problem. Version from [GitHub](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache) is much newer (and problem with nested dictionaries doesn't show up).

Comment: The above example doesn't work in the [online demo](http://mustache.github.com/#demo) still, as it uses very old version (0.2.3-dev [source](http://mustache.github.io/extras/mustache.js)), where as the latest version is 0.7.2, as of today.

Answer (score 0):

Unless we know what happens to `context` under:

```
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pystache\template.py", line 43, in render
 result = self.render_tags(template, context)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pystache\template.py", line 97, in render_tags
 replacement = func(self, tag_name, context)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pystache\template.py", line 105, in render_tag
 raw = context.get(tag_name, '')
```

it would be hard to know why it fails and why the workaround succeeds, because in the end, `context` should be a `dict` not a `str`.

I recommend you submit this issue to pystache. They take their issues seriously looking at their [**page**](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache/issues).

Comment: It looks like pystache 0.3.1 is a bit outdated. Thanks to you I just tried aersion directly from repository and it worked properly.
I think online-demo is a different problem. Now I need to check if Objective-C and Java versions work as expected.